# How encapsulated is a C++ lambda, can it delete its "containing" object?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm adding a button to my containing instance like this:

```
pPromptDlg->addBtn("Okay", [](int &loopState) {
    loopState = GlobalDefs::kGameRequestingBack;
}, true);//true because it handles the "back" button
```

I'm going to get it to set an `int` member (to an `enum` value) of its containing instance indicating it's no longer required but this is cumbersome and potentially dangerous so I'd prefer to try

```
pPromptDlg->addBtn("Okay", [](int &loopState) {
    loopState = GlobalDefs::kGameRequestingBack;
    delete pPromptDlg;
    pPromptDlg = nullptr;
}, true);
```

Then I can just check `if (pPromptDlg)` and leave it alone.
I know lambda's effectively setup a class, much like `enum` classes but `enum`'s require resolution to the class containing their definition so I am guessing there will be side effects for deleting that class's instance in a lambda?

Is this possible or just lazy? Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (unless `loopState` and `pPromptDlg` are global, which would be horrible).  I am guessing this code is supposed to run within a class method, and those two variables are members of the class?  In which case, `[this]` instead of `[]` makes the code compile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just have to capture `pPromptDlg` to do that:

```
pPromptDlg->addBtn("Okay", [&pPromptDlg](int &loopState) {
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ by reference, so that...
    loopState = GlobalDefs::kGameRequestingBack;
    delete pPromptDlg;
    pPromptDlg = nullptr; // <-- ... this line does something meaningful*
}, true);
```

*By meaningful, I mean that capturing by reference will allow you to set the `pPromptDlg` external to the lambda to `nullptr`. However, the line is still useful even in a by-value capture because it will gracefully handle the case where the lambda is called multiple times.

Comment: The line does something meaningful anyway. It prevents bad things to happen if the lambda is called twice.

Comment: @Columbo Only if the variable is captured by reference, like explained in the *two* comments in the code snippet.

Comment: Duplication of calling is exactly what I'm adding this code to avoid, so thanks, for now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If the lambda is called twice with `pPromptDlg` being captured by value, and the last line omitted, what will happen?

Comment: @Columbo Only the local *copy* inside the lambda will be set to `nullptr`, the actual captured variable will not be modified.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg *with the last line omitted* - you're calling `delete` on the same non-null pointer value twice. UB.

Comment: @Columbo No difference, the pointer will be deleted, and the original variable will still point to the (now deleted) memory, just like if the variable was captured by value and the nullptr-assignment still there. Remember that capture by value is no different than passing an argument by value, the variable is *copied*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What do you mean by "no difference"? Let me assure you that UB does make a difference. Tell me again what happens if you call `[pPromptDlg](int&) {delete pPromptDlg;}` twice.

Comment: Warning: capturing by reference is probably going to break, unless `addBtn` does **not** store the lambda.  And I bet it does store the lambda.  `&` capture is dangerous, be careful.

Comment: @Columbo Yes it's UB, I know. The problem is the `nullptr` assignment, if you capture `pPromptDlg` by value then it doesn't matter if you do the `nullptr` assignment or not, as doing the assignment will only change the *copy in the lambda*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that is bluntly obvious. And totally unrelated to the point I tried to raise. I'm trying to say that the line isn't completely meaningless as it enables the lambda to be called several times without invoking UB.

Comment: @Columbo Then I just misunderstood you. The comment for that line about it doing something useful must be read as a continuation of the first comment about capturing the variable by reference, your phrasing made me believe that the line would be useful either way which is not true.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see - I should've made my point clearer then, sorry.

Comment: @Columbo This is a good point. I updated my answer to clarify what I had intended.

Comment: @Yakk, you were right, I couldn't get any self deletion working from within the lambda where the deleted object held a reference to the lambda. Luckily found I already had clean up code in the event handler that propagated to the `addBtn`, and set up some plain data guards against reentry.